# What's happened in endswith function in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file,named`test.txt`

```
182.7 100.0
182.6 100.0
182.8 100.0
```

I want to sure weather the line ends with the digits `100.0`:
So I use the following code:

```
for line in open('test.txt','rt'):
    print repr(line),line.endswith('100.0\n')
    print
```

But the Output in Ubuntu is:

> '182.7 100.0\r\n' False
>
> '182.6 100.0\r\n' False
>
> '182.8 100.0' False

But the Output in windows server 2008 is:

> '182.7 100.0\n' True
>
> '182.6 100.0\n' True
>
> '182.8 100.0' False

I already using `rt` in open function,so why there is difference between different systems yet?

Comment: Please provide a better [mcve]. What does your data look like?

Comment: You didn't show the output, so hard to guess what the confusion is.  Here's one confusion:  `len("100.0\n")` is 6, not 7.  `"\n"` denotes a string with a single character.

Comment: @TimPeters I will fix it

Comment: Please change the first print to `print repr(line)`.  That's the only way for anyone to know what's really in the line.  For example, perhaps there's a space before the newline.  That's impossible to determine from the output shown, but will be clear if you add `repr()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks!  Is the answer obvious now?  The file was created on Windows, where lines end with `"\r\n"`, not with `"\n"`.  So long as you read the file *on* Windows in text mode, Python can hide that from you.  But you read the file on Linux, where the distinction between "text" and "binary" modes doesn't exist, and you get exactly whatever bytes are in the file.

My advice is to force line ends to the native convention on whatever platform you move files to.  Short of that, in Python 2 you can open files in "universal newline mode" instead, as [briefly explained here](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/01/file-modes-in-python-text-binary-and.html).

Comment: It _does_ do that conversion, but only on Windows.  On Linux there is absolutely no difference (in Python 2) among "rt", "rb", and "r".  Please follow the link I already gave to the discussion of universal newline mode, which converts all known platform line endings to plain "\n" on all platforms.  That can't be done "for free", which is why I prefer converting files to platform-native conventions.  It's not just Python that will get confused by using platform-inappropriate line endings.

Comment: Tkank you,you are welcomed!  I knon what is happening now.

Answer (score 3):

The function `strip()` can take care of the ending new line character, and it is independent of the operating system used, the code can be

```
print "{line} {expr}".format(line=repr(line), expr=line.rstrip().endswith('100.0'))
```